# Определить две самые близкие к началу координат точки из n имеющихся

Tags: c++

подскажите пожалуйста как можно перебрать весь вектор pair и выбрать оттуда и две самые близкие в началу координат?
Перебирать такой формулой (прикрепляю) все координаты через циклы и сравнивать = самоубийство
Может кто знает как можно это быстрее сделать? Спасибо заранее

```
a = sqrt((V[i].first * V[i].first) + (V[i].second * V[i].second));
b = sqrt((V[j].first * V[j].first) + (V[j].second * V[j].second));
```

Comment: можно без sqrt. ну и да, почему самоубийство? Ничего лучше `O(n)` тут придумать нельзя, а `O(n)` тривиален.

Comment: у меня 20 точек, и переписывать всё все 20 раз как-то не знаю)

Comment: А как минимум циклы ещё не изобрели, чтобы это Вы это вручную писали? Про встроенные функции я уже вообще молчу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашей постановке - если готовая функция - то просто применить `nth_element`, примерно как

```
auto it = nth_element(v.begin(),v.begin()+2,v.end(),
                      [](auto a, auto b)
                      { return a.first*a.first +a.second*a.second <
                               b.first*b.first +b.second*b.second; });
```

Замечу, что `sqrt` тут не нужен.

О сложности [`nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element):

> O(N) applications of the predicate, and O(N log N) swaps, where N = last - first.

Но руками, поддерживая два минимальных значения и сравнивая каждый элемент с ними - это вычисление (расстояния) получится n раз.

Если массив огромный или надо делать такое часто - лучше при каждом элементе держать его расстояние до начала координат для повышения эффективности...