# как отсортировать вектор pair<float,float> по модулю элементов?

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector

у меня задача на нахождения двух самых ближних точек к началу координат

координаты не все положительные, естественно

хотел отсортировать по модулям элементов, потом взять две первые (минимальные) и вывести

не могу сделать сортировку по модулям

сделал так, но не работает `sort(V.begin(), V.end(), [](pair<float,float> a, pair<float, float> b) { return abs(a) < abs(b);});`

подскажите как правильнее было бы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`abs` для `pair` вы сами перегрузили? Если нет, то учтите, что стандартная функция `abs` с парами работать не умеет. Или пишите

```
floaf abs(pair<float,float> a) { 
    return sqrt(a.first*a.first+a.second*a.second); }
```

или

```
floaf abs(pair<float,float> a) { return hypot(a.first, a.second); }
```

(второй вариант работает даже там, где первый в переполнение вылетит, но медленнее), либо сразу правильно пишите лямбду -

```
[](const pair<float,float>& a, const pair<float, float>& b) { 
    return a.first*a.first+a.second*a.second < 
           b.first*b.first+b.second*b.second;}
```

Сортировать, кстати, - не самый эффективный способ. См. [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1119268/195342).